# Is sharing dataset in the Bigquery is migration?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, migration

We need to migrate the data from the old GCP instance to new instance( with new organization node). I am using the "share dataset" option to move the data. It is very convenient approach. Do you think this is a good way to migrate data or should we create new tables and then load the data into the tables?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the new instance a GCP as well? or another platform like azure, aws?

Comment: New instance is GCP as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on what you want to achieve. The share dataset feature allow other to access the data because you have granted the permission.

However, the data doesn't move and still belong to the old GCP project. If you remove the project, you remove the data. In addition, it's still the old project that pay for the data storage, the new one only for the data processing.

If you plan to shut down the old project,  you have to copy the data. Automatically with the data transfert service, or by querying them if you want to filter/transform the existing data before storing them in the new project.

Comment: That's a great explanation, Thank you @guillaume blaquiere.  In that case I will have to copy the data to the new instance, is there a method/ command which makes it easier to copy/move the data between two GCP instances.(old Bigquery instance to new Bigquery instance).

Comment: As I said: BigQuery data transfer service is free and you copy a dataset to another one (and they don't have to be in the same region). You can't select the tables of filter the data in them. If you query the data, you can perform an insert-select of only the table and the data (filter) that you want. However, you can't change the region, and you will pay the volume of data that you process. Anyway, the easiest way is the data transfer service. You will be able to play with the data after!